# same class in different views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an App with 3 views, and 2 classes that each take care of parsing messages and connecting to a server.

The thing is, i would need to use the parser in all three views (and the connection too)
But i think that including and initializing an instance of both in all views may not be correct performance wise, am i right?

It it's not correct, how should i do it?
I am thinking about creating an instance of them in appDelegate, but i don't know how
to do it to use the methods of the instances.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing back to the AppDelegate is possible, but not really OOP is it? Pretty soon you'll be using it to pass data back and forward between view controllers in larger application.

The better way to do it, and similar to the way you pass the managed object context around in Core Data programs is to create a property in the view controllers to hold the parser. Create this parser in one place and after you create the new view controllers, set the property to point to your parser. That way you are just passing around one instance, and in in a more controlled manner.

Comment: Ok, i think i understood, but i`m not familiar with Core Data yet, 
and i will look into how to do the way you said, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It will be better in this case to create it in the appDelegate. The appDelegate can be reached anywhere in the code as follows:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate=(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate parse:data];
```

Comment: Ok i got the hang of it i think. The thing is, for example, my Connection has the method authenticate: and Connection is initialized in my appDelegate.
If i want to call the method authenticate: in my third view, how should i do it? doing [appDelegate authenticate:data] gives me a warning about response..